# Resolving absolute paths from css with Webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a project where I'm importing CSS rules from node_modules. They have clip paths to them, with absolute URLS, so these don't work with the current set up.

I am trying to resolve it with Webpack, because it would generally make it work for all images.

My webpack set up is:

```
{
  test: /\.(css|scss)?$/,
  use:  ['style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
},
{
  test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|eot|woff|woff2)?$/,
  include: [
       path.resolve(basePath, 'project/frontend/scss'),
  ],
  use: {
  loader: "file-loader",
  options: {
  name: '[name].[ext]',
  outputPath: 'assets/fonts/'
   }
}
```

I have a stylesheet that contains this style (coming from node_modules):

```
.background {
   background: url('/img/image.svg');
   font-color: '#cecece';
}
```

The styles are being added to the HTML, and the `font-colour` is being applied. However, the style can't resolve the path, because upon importing the styles, for some reason it can't find the image within its submodule, so the other option is to make it relative, and allow it to find it:

```
.background {
   background: url('./img/image.svg');
}
```

But I can't resolve it with my web pack configuration. I tried this, because I have a submodule that contains the images (and styles as well). The intention is to use to develop on top a small concept of another app.

But I can't figure out how to map the paths to the images, and I wouldn't want to resolve all the image paths from the initial project if I can avoid it.

It doesn't give any error but simply doesn't resolve the path '/img/image.svg'.

I have tried a number of solutions, all of them unsuccessfully. So, I'd like to know if there are any idea or solution I'm missing.

Comment: Can you tell a bit more it ? you styles aren't being applied. ?

Comment: Thanks, I further developed the question to add more information about it. I hope it helps, I think one solution would be through aliases.. but having been able to put it correctly.

Comment: Can you share it over github so I can figure out the configurations